# Conditionally delete Parent Node if Children nodes are empty

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

As the title describes I am trying to take xml like this:

```
<Measurement>
    <Name>Board_1_Output_0</Name>
    <LongIdentifier>Board 1 Output 0<LongIdentifier/>
    ...
    <ECUAddress>2000000F</ECUAddress>
</Measurement>
<Measurement>
    <Name/>
    <LongIdentifier/>
    ...
    <ECUAddress/>
</Measurement>
```

and conditionally delete `<Measurement>` if any child nodes of `<Measurement>` are empty like this:

```
<Measurement>
    <Name>Board_1_Output_0</Name>
    <LongIdentifier>Board 1 Output 0<LongIdentifier/>
    ...
    <ECUAddress>2000000F</ECUAddress>
</Measurement>
```

My current xslt, for this section, looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Measurement">
    <xsl:text>/begin MEASUREMENT</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>/* Name           */&#x09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select ="Name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="LongIdentifier">
    <xsl:text>ECU_ADDRESS&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;&#x09;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select ="ECUAddress"/>
<xsl:text>/end MEASUREMENT</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each ><!-- Measurement -->
```

I thought I could conditionally look at each section and not print any `<Measurment>` XML tags if ANY of the children tags are empty, however, I can only achieve leaving the parent `<Measurement>` element as such:

```
<Measurement></Measurement>
```

Is there a way to delete the parent xml node when I find that I have an empty child in the same xslt stylesheet? Or do I need to run the xml through a different stylesheet to delete any XML nodes that have empty children?

Comment: Shouldn't both "Measurement" tags be deleted then, because both have a child element "LongIdentifier" which is empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove parent node if a child node is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539910/remove-parent-node-if-a-child-node-is-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some XPath in your `for-each` to filter out `<Measurement>` elements. If you want to remove all such elements where *any* child element is empty, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Measurement[not(*[. = ''])]">
     ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

i.e. only select `<Measurement>` elements where there are not any child elements that are empty.

Comment: Or better, move the whole thing into a template match and only match on this ... xsl:template match="Measurement[not(*[.=''])]", then use apply-templates.

Comment: @BenL For some reason, your answer did not work completely - adding the XPath code deletes all Measurements. However, when I change the XPath code to `Measurement[not(Name[. = ''])]`, it works perfectly... Very weird. But I am doing the transformation inside Excel 2003, so maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: @KevinBrown is totally right - that would be the most idiomatic way to write the stylesheet.

Comment: @larrylampco, it seems to work for me. Did you get it working as I wrote it in the end, or did you stick with your change? (I'm wondering whether you tested it with the XML that was originally in your question, or the current edited version.)

Comment: Note; I only replicated what was posted before ... I would actually do something different using a match but examining Measurement[not(normalized-space(*)='')] or something like that

Comment: @BenL I got it to work with the current edited version. Looks like I need to go learn some XPath syntax!