# XSL 1.0 - Hiding Child nodes when child element is Null

Tags: xslt-1.0, parent-child

I have been trying to make child elements of my structure hide based upon them being empty.
From reading other posts I found this [Remove parent node if a child node is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539910/remove-parent-node-if-a-child-node-is-empty) but I don't understand it enough to implement it in my XSL. I have had a try at applying the linked post to my XSL but it does not make the desired changes to my output.

So my XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<exchange>
<sce>
<sce.srs>
<sce_scjc.sce.srs>140008305/1</sce_scjc.sce.srs>
<sce_seq2.sce.srs>01</sce_seq2.sce.srs>
<sce_stuc.sce.srs>140008305</sce_stuc.sce.srs>
<spr>
<spr.cams>
<spr_code.spr.cams>140008305/1</spr_code.spr.cams>
<prs_code.spr.cams>77711925</prs_code.spr.cams>
<prs>
<prs.mensys>
<prs_code.prs.mensys>77711925</prs_code.prs.mensys>
<prs_name.prs.mensys>Johan</prs_name.prs.mensys>
</prs.mensys>
</prs>
</spr.cams>
</spr>
</sce.srs>
<sce.srs>
<sce_scjc.sce.srs>151516736/1</sce_scjc.sce.srs>
<sce_seq2.sce.srs>01</sce_seq2.sce.srs>
<sce_stuc.sce.srs>151516736</sce_stuc.sce.srs>
<spr>
<spr.cams>
<spr_code.spr.cams>151516736/1</spr_code.spr.cams>
<prs_code.spr.cams>77709062</prs_code.spr.cams>
<prs>
<prs.mensys>
<prs_code.prs.mensys>77709062</prs_code.prs.mensys>
<prs_name.prs.mensys>Evangelia</prs_name.prs.mensys>
</prs.mensys>
</prs>
</spr.cams>
</spr>
</sce.srs>
<sce.srs>
<sce_scjc.sce.srs>150052468/1</sce_scjc.sce.srs>
<sce_seq2.sce.srs>01</sce_seq2.sce.srs>
<sce_stuc.sce.srs>150052468</sce_stuc.sce.srs>
<spr>
<spr.cams>
<spr_code.spr.cams>150052468/1</spr_code.spr.cams>
<prs_code.spr.cams/>
</spr.cams>
</spr>
</sce.srs>
</sce>
</exchange>
```

And my XSL looks like the passaage below. I have a nil element template that I added in as I thought looking for a value was easier than looking for a nulll so happy for it to come out if not needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="xd" version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/exchange/sce">
<ImportTask>
<EntityRelationshipEntities>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</EntityRelationshipEntities>
</ImportTask>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nilElement">
<xsl:param name="value"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string($value)">
<xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:nil" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">True</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sce.srs[not(*/AttributeValue[not(@AttributeValue='True')])]">
<xsl:for-each select="spr/spr.cams">
<EntityRelationshipEntity>
<ErRef>ERREF_21</ErRef>
<EntityCode><xsl:value-of select="../../sce_stuc.sce.srs"/></EntityCode>
<AttributeValue>
<xsl:call-template name="nilElement">
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="prs/prs.mensys/prs_name.prs.mensys"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</AttributeValue>
<Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
</EntityRelationshipEntity>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template match="AttributeValue[@AttributeValue = 'True']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So this currently gives me:

```
<ImportTask xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EntityRelationshipEntities>
<EntityRelationshipEntity>
<ErRef>ERREF_21</ErRef>
<EntityCode>151514490</EntityCode>
<AttributeValue xsi:nil="True"/>
<Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
</EntityRelationshipEntity>
<EntityRelationshipEntity>
<ErRef>ERREF_21</ErRef>
<EntityCode>140008305</EntityCode>
<AttributeValue>Johan</AttributeValue>
<Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
</EntityRelationshipEntity>
<EntityRelationshipEntity>
<EntityCode>151516736</EntityCode>
<AttributeValue>Evangelia</AttributeValue>
<Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
</EntityRelationshipEntity>
</EntityRelationshipEntities>
</ImportTask>
```

What I would like to produce is out those where  is not null. This would mean that the child below is not output:

```
<EntityRelationshipEntity>
<ErRef>ERREF_21</ErRef>
<EntityCode>151514490</EntityCode>
<AttributeValue xsi:nil="True"/>
<Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
</EntityRelationshipEntity>
```

But the others would be output something like this:

```
<ImportTask xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EntityRelationshipEntities>
<EntityRelationshipEntity>
<ErRef>ERREF_21</ErRef>
<EntityCode>140008305</EntityCode>
<AttributeValue>Johan</AttributeValue>
<Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
</EntityRelationshipEntity>
<EntityRelationshipEntity>
<EntityCode>151516736</EntityCode>
<AttributeValue>Evangelia</AttributeValue>
<Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
</EntityRelationshipEntity>
</EntityRelationshipEntities>
</ImportTask>
```

Can someone help me apply this correctly?

Many thanks

Jonah

Comment: Why is `<ErRef>ERREF_21</ErRef>` missing from the last `<EntityRelationshipEntity>` in both your current output and the expected one?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, its my fault, I tried to cut down the original XML to be smaller, easier to read and must have cut out the <ErRef> line. Sorry, my error. 
I'm not confident enough on manipulating the select statement so started trying other ways to make it work. Can I ask a question? In the select below:
       select="sce.srs/spr/spr.cams[string(prs/prs.mensys/prs_name.prs.mensys) 
Am I correct thinking the String function is being used on prs_name as it will only return items where the string length is greater than zero?

Comment: Yes, the predicate (the expression in square brackets) is used to exclude nodes where the expression returns false - and an empty string returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing something, but couldn't this be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/exchange/sce">
    <ImportTask xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <EntityRelationshipEntities>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sce.srs/spr/spr.cams[string(prs/prs.mensys/prs_name.prs.mensys)]"/>
        </EntityRelationshipEntities>
    </ImportTask>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="spr.cams">
    <EntityRelationshipEntity>
        <ErRef>ERREF_21</ErRef>
        <EntityCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../sce_stuc.sce.srs"/>
        </EntityCode>
        <AttributeValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="prs/prs.mensys/prs_name.prs.mensys"/>
        </AttributeValue>
        <Action>VALUEONLY</Action>
    </EntityRelationshipEntity>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```